# How to form a new square with 3 squares of sides 2 cm, 3 cm and 6 cm?

Tags: geometry, area

> A square lamina is made from three square laminae, whose sides are 2
>   cm, 3 cm and 6 cm. The side of the new square lamina is
>
> 1. 11 cm
> 2. 10 cm
> 3. 7 cm
> 4. 9 cm

I'm able solved this problem but the question is not clear to me, maybe my approach is wrong.

Can someone help me to understand how the new square has been formed with the 3 given squares, with the help of a figure if possible?

The question neither mention of melting the laminae nor any hint of that as it is found in the problems related to volumes.

The answer is **7 cm**.

Comment: There isn't a way to assemble these three squares into a third square - it would have to be at least $8$ cm on a side due to the geometry. As far as I can tell, the problem is just asking you to recognize that $2^3 + 3^2 + 6^2 = 7^2$.

Comment: @user296602 Is 2^2 + 3^2 + 6^2 = 7^2 any important series or simply has it been asked and has no geometrical importance? Do the question has any merit if the options are removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply not possible. Either the question is wrong, or the question writer assumes some "laminae" which can be broken up into smaller pieces (maybe 1x1 squares) and rearranged to a $7x7$ square. Either way, the important piece of information is

$$2^2 + 3^2 + 6^2 = 7^2$$

which gives you the answer of 7.

Comment: This is a govt civil service selection question so I have assumed that the question is not wrong unless there are some printing mistakes in the book from where I have got it. While solving I assumed that the laminae have dx amount of thickness so they have a volume. If I take the sum of the volumes to comes to 49dx. With respect to the question, I omitted the dx the root of 49 gave me 7. Is my approach correct?

Comment: @NewBee Your method is correct, except you can skip the dx and the notion of volume, all that's interesting is the area. They sum up to 49, for which a square has side length $\sqrt 49 = 7$.